# Woocommerce guest domain whitelist on checkout

Tags: wordpress, validation, woocommerce, checkout, whitelist

I need to create a woocommerce shop for guest users only (**customer registration will not be possible** due to my clients company regulations).
Is there any way to restrict customer address domain to a specific domain?

My clinet wants me to make a woocommerce gift shop for his employees (a "shop" with free swag items for company workers), and checkout should be possible only after providing email address with companys domain in checkout form.

Is there any way to whitelist only one or two specific domain in email field in guest checkout form?

Thenk you for your help,
Krzysiek

Answer (score 0):

Place the following function in your functions.php - https://prnt.sc/O2V_i9B-Frf-

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'check_domain_email_addresses');
function check_domain_email_addresses() { 
    $email = $_POST['billing_email'];
    //Replace with your domains
    $allowed = [
        'gmail.com',
        'yahoo.com',
    ];
    // Make sure the address is valid
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        // Separate string by @ characters (there should be only one)
        $parts = explode('@', $email);

        // Remove and return the last part, which should be the domain
        $domain = array_pop($parts);

        // Check if the domain is in our list
        if ( ! in_array($domain, $allowed))
        {
            wc_add_notice( 'Use company email address', 'error' );
        }
    }    
}
```